# cannot import name 'serve' from 'waitress'

Tags: flask, wsgi

My Sample Flask Code (wsgitest.py):

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/wait')
def index():
    return ("<h3>Hello World</h3>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

waitress
Version: 1.4.3

Error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'serve' from 'waitress' (C:\.....\wsgitest.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your your project has one file named `waitress`. Import resolves to your project file rather than `waitress` package

your code is ok. I copy your code to my idea, it's run successfully